# osrf/ros2:testing docker image not working

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running:

```
docker pull osrf/ros2:testing
docker run -it osrf/ros2:testing
```

Throws an error:

```
/ros_entrypoint.sh: line 5: /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the docker image broken?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384277/osrf/ros2:testing-docker-image-not-working/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2021-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT:

This was intended behaviour. Quoting from a [response to the issue](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/560#issuecomment-898199427),

> While the `osrf/ros2:testing` does include the same `ros_entrypoint.sh` script to keep it interchangeable with other ros image tags, it does not pre-install any ros specific packages, as it is intended to be used as a base image for child Dockerfiles that would install user specified ros dependencies. If you do want to spawn containers directly from the `osrf/ros2:testing` tag, you could override the default entrypoint by specifying a different one via the docker run arg:
>
> ```
> docker run -it --rm --entrypoint="" osrf/ros2:testing
> ```

---

ORIGINAL:

I've raised an [issue in osrf/docker_images](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/560) about this.

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2021-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0